# How to determine hostname for a running Docker container?

Tags: docker, api, continuous-integration, integration-testing, pytest

I'm fairly new to Docker and have learnt a fair bit recently, but this one thing I can't understand.

If I run a simple application with an api in a docker container on my local machine, I can access it from outside of docker via http://localhost/... etc. If I try to run integration tests against on my local machine, I can still user http://localhost/... But when I try to run these tests on a CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab for example, connection is refused. The host is different. Sometimes I can use http://docker/... but this doesn't always seem to work.

Is there some full proof way to establish what the host should be to interact with a Docker container? Or have I completely misunderstood some fundamentals here?

For more context, I am trying to write integration tests with pytest and the docker sdk (https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). I can start up and shut down the containers I want to test against, but can't ever establish what the hostname should be of these services when I want to call an API endpoint.

Comment: Is the CI environment itself running inside Docker, or otherwise has some setup that's not running directly on the same host as the Docker daemon?  Launching integration test dependencies from inside a container can wind up being tricky (bind mounts are the other thing that can act unintuitively).

Comment: I understand the CI "runner" is itself a container - allowing for  "Docker in Docker". I'm still learning how this works.

Comment: I am slowly coming to the conclusion that I need to run my tests inside a new container that is on the same network as other containers I want to test against, I hadn't appreciated this approach before and it still feels a bit odd, but am experimenting.